# How Do I Initialise The Vault For Testing

Tags: corda

I want to test a flow that expects several Cash States to exist.

At the moment I have to run 2 other flows before I can run my flow under test.

Obviously this isn't a great test as one of the other flows could fail before my actual test code starts.

How can I initialise the vault directly before running my test?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `VaultFiller` class that is used internally by some Corda tests to pre-fill the vault without using flows.

- It is defined here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/testing/test-utils/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/testing/internal/vault/VaultFiller.kt
- You can see a sample usage here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/finance/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/CashTests.kt#L98

Comment: FYI: For v2 these are in the ServiceHub bank1.services.fillWithSomeTestCash(100.DOLLARS, megaCorpServices, 1, megaCorp.ref(1), ourIdentity)